# How execute Android gradle task after build bundle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy

I have simple command line to execute and wrote this task:

```
task signBundle(type: Exec) {
    doLast {
        workingDir "$projectDir/release/"
        commandLine 'bash', '-c', "java -jar file.jar"
     }
}
```

Task works if remove doLast clojure and run it from command line:
*./gradlew signBundle*.
But I need run it after build release bundle and tried without results this:

```
tasks.getByName('build').dependsOn(signBundle)
```

and this:

```
build.finalizedBy(signBundle)
```

and this (but there is no method execute):

```
gradle.buildFinished {
   signBundle.execute()
}
```

and even this (depricated):

```
    android {
        project.gradle.addBuildListener(new BuildListener() {
              @Override
              void buildFinished(BuildResult result) {
              ...
```

And really strange that in build logs you can see many tasks but can't get them from tasks set for make dependsOn.